# Seeing the active css element outline style in chrome developer tooling?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In chrome the below button will retain it's outline after it has been clicked.  If I looked at the buttons css settings after selecting the :active checkbox in chrome's developer tools I still can't see what the CSS values are for the outline.  It appears to be about 1px in width and grey visually, but I don't see these values.  Is there a way to see them?

```html
<body>
  <button style="background-color: aquamarine; margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 50px;">HI</button>
</body>
```

In other words google chrome does add this style (As indicated by one of the answer below):

```
 :focus {
     outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
 }
```

However when I click the `focus` checkbox in order to be able to see all the CSS that is triggered by focus, I don't see that style in the developer tooling pane ... Is it a google developer tooling bug or do other people see it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are actually two different styles that are automatically applied through through the user agent stylesheet to buttons; the **[pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)** **[`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afocus)** and **[`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aactive)**:

```
:focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
button:active {
    border-style: inset;
}
```

The `:focus` only applies to Chrome, and is responsible for the blue border you are seeing. Overriding this fixes the problem:

```css
button:focus {
    outline: none; /* Remove the outline */
}
button.active: {
    border-style: none; /* Remove the border */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button style="background-color: aquamarine; margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 50px;">HI</button>
</body>
```

You can see that the `:focus` is getting added in the Developer Console through the user agent stylesheet (just below the inline elements in this screenshot):

[image: :focus]

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi - Thanks - I updated my question a bit with information from your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, and apologies for my slow response. You should indeed be able to see the `:focus` pseudo-class by right-clicking on the button element and checking `:focus`. It should appear just below inline styles on the right. I've tested this on two different computers, and just updated my answer to provide a screenshot showcasing this. If you can't replicate this, it's probably an addon conflicting with your stylesheets, or a bug. Hope that helps clarify :)

Comment: Thanks again for the heads up.  I'm creating a button component that should serve as a good baseline for incremental design.  So far I have this: https://github.com/superfly-css/superfly-css-component-button/blob/master/src/main/css/index.css ... If you see anything that could be better I would love another heads up - Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post a link to the website?

In the meantime, I would suggest looking the "Computed" styles tab

Side note about why this might be happening--I've noticed sometimes I haven't been able to see the `:active` styles when it's JavaScript controlling the button's state

Edit: Hi Ole, I can see your demo, thanks.

Based on Obsidian Age's helpful reply, I ran this code snippet and it got rid of the borders on click. That's the behavior you want, right?

```html
<body>
<style>
button:focus {
    outline: none; // Remove the outline
 border-top: none;
    border-width: 0;
}
button.active: {
    border-style: none; //Remove the border
}
</style>
  <button style="background-color: aquamarine; margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 50px;">HI</button>
</body>
```

By looking in the "Computed" tab (next to "Styles" when you're inspecting an element in Chrome), I saw that there was a gray, 2px-wide border-top, -right, -bottom, -left for the button. For some reason it was enough just to set the border-top property to none and the border-width to 0. I don't know why but I tried a bunch of other combinations that didn't work--this did it with the least amount of CSS.

Comment: Are you able to see the active button outline style in the demo I posted above?

Answer (score 2):

The styles console in the chrome developer tools only shows what is currently selected in it's current state. If you want to see the rules for the other states a simple way is to go to the css file it self. To do that next to the element class there is a link as shown in the image below. Clicking this will open the actual css file in the specific row of the selected class. Assuming the other states are declared close to that you'll be able to locate the class you want.

[image]